# Stripe Account Card Number

Tags: stripe-payments, stripe-connect

I have a Stripe's Platform and already have connected accounts.All I need to do is transfer money between connected user,that's why I already made a Stripe's Connection.My question is: If the user is already connected to my platform, does he/she have to type card details every payment through Stripe's Platform?

Answer (score 1):

Once you have credit card details , you can create a token ( or card id ) and re-use this token again , without storing a credit card details ( but storing a token itself ).

First you have to obtain credit card details,
then use Stripe`s API method to actually create a card object,
it will return the ID ( or token ) of the card ,
after this , you can always retrieve the card object with this card-id,

The actual implementation depends on the technology/programming language you use.

Have a look at this 
https://stripe.com/docs/tutorials/charges
https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_card
https://support.stripe.com/questions/can-i-save-a-card-and-charge-it-later

Comment: The answer is good,but I use PayumBundle and the main capture make that bundle automatically.Do you suggest anything good?

Comment: I use Stripe`s own SDK both on Backend and Client , client creates a token , sends to the backend , backend attaches this token to the user and once charging is needed , creates a card with a token and makes a charge. Unfortunately I do not have experience with PayumBundle , sorry